# Appending Python Lists to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to find if a tag is present in a list and then map them to a dictionary and add them to the corresponding tag.
This is what I came up with.

```
RequiredTags = ['PolicyNumber', 'PaymentAmt', 'PolicyAmt']
ListOfTags = ['Header', 'Version','PolicyNumber', 'PaymentAmt', 'Body', 'PolicyAmt']
ListOfValues = ['', '1.1', '123456', '100.00', '', '1']

values = dict.fromkeys(RequiredTags, [])
for key, value in values.items():
    if key in ListOfTags:
        v = ListOfValues[ListOfTags.index(key)]
        print(key, v)
        values[key].append(v)
```

The problem is, everytime a value is appended, it is appended to every key in the dictionary and not just the one which I'm trying to append to.

Expected output is like

```
values = {'PolicyNumber': ['123456'], 'PaymentAmt': ['100.00'], 'PolicyAmt': ['1']}
```

I have a list of xml files, i want to extract and export values from.

This will add the values to the dict for one file but I want to append the values from all XML files to this one dictionary.
Hope this clarifies the question better.

Comment: I think you are over-complicating what you want to achieve.

Comment: Your edit made your question harder to understand. I am not sure what you meant by *"If i pass another list in a function, then these values also should be appended to the list inside the dict"*. You need to put some example in order to help us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to make much sense but what I inferred was that the required output should  correspond to the list of required tags.

```
values = dict.fromkeys(RequiredTags)
for i, tag in enumerate(ListOfTags):
    if tag in RequiredTags:
        values[tag] = ListOfValues[i]
```

which returns the following:

```
{'PaymentAmt': '100.00', 'PolicyAmt': '1', 'PolicyNumber': '123456'}
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

**EDIT:**

So, this is what I think you want:

```
values = {}
for i, tag in enumerate(ListOfTags):
    if tag in RequiredTags:
        values.setdefault(tag, []).append(ListOfValues[i])
```

In the last line if the key exists in the dict, then it appends to the list of values otherwise it initialises the value with an empty array.

Comment: kind of. I wanted to add the values as a list and append them again with another list of values